# parsing data from json php get image src

Tags: php

I want to parse data from JSON Instagram without API, 
a result like this

```
Array ( [nodes] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [__typename] => GraphVideo [id] => 1532294365652508146 [comments_disabled] => [dimensions] => Array ( [height] => 750 [width] => 750 ) [gating_info] => [media_preview] => ACoq6aiionJGTQBLRWXLOwJySuFyATjv16j2496dbu8mQWJwAVPqp6H69jQBpUUg6UtABWLfXslvkjBGcAEVtVxOoO09w69FRj9Bj+poASC5kklJkO7cDn8fT2rTsJminEJ5XG36dx+XeseAHf8APkg8Z7EfX04pxuvs0xaMDAOQD0zigDuaWooX8yNXP8Sg/mM1LQAVEYIySSq5PX5Rz9eKlooAiEEYGAqgfQU020J5KIf+Aj/Cp6KAEAAGBwBS0UUAf//Z [owner] => Array ( [id] => 6860189 ) [thumbnail_src] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/18888588_1753665424925670_2681598092939100160_n.jpg [is_video] => 1 [code] => BVDzZtsDN3y [date] => 1496883744 [display_src] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/18888588_1753665424925670_2681598092939100160_n.jpg [video_views] => 2304729 [caption] => #2U Friday @romeestrijd [comments] => Array ( [count] => 18485 ) [likes] => Array ( [count] => 985087 ) ) [1] => Array ( [__typename] => GraphVideo [id] => 1532284690492268192 [comments_disabled] => [dimensions] => Array ( [height] => 750 [width] => 750 ) [gating_info] => [media_preview] => ACoq6aikNU7ycwwF1wDwAT0GSBn8KALlGa5u21KSGRVmbzI3ON5GME9MHuP89q6OgB1FJS0AIaytVRntG29sH64Nap6Vg6xKUtlXOGY9B0IHJ+vOPzoA56SVnQZ9evoR6eldtZzieJXyMkDODnBxXCNOzrtOPr3rZ0ViHCDo27d+XH9KAOsoqpZwPBHskbeck556enOat0AJVG606O6ADlgF6AEY+vIP0/8A1VfooAw/+Eft/V/zH/xNXbPTorMkoWJIx8xB/kBV+igAooooA//Z [owner] => Array ( [id] => 6860189 ) [thumbnail_src] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/18947831_1799767330352720_4657693158346326016_n.jpg [is_video] => 1 [code] => BVDxM6_j56g [date] => 1496882591 [display_src] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/18947831_1799767330352720_4657693158346326016_n.jpg [video_views] => 3116560 [caption] => #2U Friday @sarasampaio [comments] => Array ( [count] => 28703 ) [likes] => Array ( [count] => 1272010 ) ) [2] => Array ( [__typename] => GraphImage [id] => 1532046157831653372 [comments_disabled] => [dimensions] => .....
```

how to I can get a display_src result in foreach loop

```
   $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($data === null) {
        break;



    }
    $media = $data['user']['media'];


    $found += count($media['nodes']);



foreach ($media as $dataa){

echo $dataa->nodes->display_src;

}
```

I try it but I do not get result.

Comment: `nodes` is an array, so you need an index to be able to access `display_src`. I _formatted_ the array, so you can visualize it: Take a look: [https://pastebin.com/7M6qKQ17](https://pastebin.com/7M6qKQ17) - (I removed the rest cause I'm lazy)

Comment: Base on that, you'd get `display_src` with `$dataa->nodes[0]->display_src` (or something around that). If you need to grab all `display_src`, loop `nodes`.

Comment: blank_, 'nodes' only one not loop , this original json from instagram before i parsing nodes https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/?__a=1